# how to get wheel encoder count from turtlebot's /odom topic

Tags: ros, robotics

turtlebot's odom topic gives:

```
header:    seq: 406289   stamp: 
    secs: 4392
    nsecs: 160000000   frame_id: odom child_frame_id: base_footprint pose:   pose: 
    position: 
      x: 1.56701645246e-05
      y: -9.82132735628e-06
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.548275342929
      w: 0.836297882537   covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05] twist:    twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -2.67171244095e-06
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.000185729678152   covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I'd like to find the wheel encoder count from this data. How does turtlebot use wheel encoder values to compute positions? Where can I find the code that does this?